# Static methods versus template parameters in Play framework

Tags: java, templates, parameters, static, playframework-2.0

In my project using the `Play 2.0.x` framework I have *a lot* of templates. A lot of these templates take a `String` and `Lang` parameter to display the username and text in a certain language on a page.

Since these are used in nearly all templates, should I:

1. Pass the username and language as an argument to the templates?
   *or*
2. Use static methods in my models to get the username/language?

**Example of 1:**

Controller:

```
return ok(views.html.template.render(User.username(), User.language());
```

Calls template:

```
@(lang: Lang)(username : String)
<p>@Messages.get(lang, "hello") username!</p>
```

**Example of 2:**

Controller:

```
return ok(views.html.template.render());
```

Calls template:

```
<p>@Messages.get(User.language(), "hello") User.username()!</p>
```

I would like to know which method is preferred and why and if there are any disadvantages of using one above the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As actually you understand perfectly the usage way I can only advice using static methods, as you can see `@Messages` class does it and it works, otherwise you will need to pass them everytime.

Tip, to avoid redundant DB queries especially while fetching object of logged in user consider using cache API (one entry per user).